# regarding inapp purchase

Tags: iphone

I have developed one app on iphone.
I have loaded its lite version on app store.
Now i cant to load full version from app itself, how it can be done.
I know this is possible but how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways. You have have lite and full as two separate apps, or you can have in-app upgrade. Depending on how you implement the restrictions of Lite, either one or the other might be a better choice.

In the two-app scenario, you develop Full as a separate bundle, with a separate bundle id. Xcode targets and conditional compilation might come in handy for this. In the Lite version, you want to hard-code a link to the full version in the App Store. Find out the link by copy-pasting from iTunes Connect.

In the second scenario, full/lite is a run-time setting, and the upgrade package is an in-app purchase. Implement StoreKit API, provide the hard-coded in-app product ID. Once the upgrade purchase is noticed (it's an asynchronous process), flip the setting to Full.

I'd recommend the second approach. For one thing, all reviews would go under Lite version, as opposed to splitting between Lite and Full. Also, if your app has settings or data files, those won't be lost on upgrade.

EDIT: here's how implementation of in-app purchases might look like. Somewhere in the app there's an Upgrade button (link, image, whatever) that goes like this:

```
if(![SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
{
    //Display the "cannot pay here" message
    return;
}

@try
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
        addPayment:[SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier: @"com.mydomain.myproduct.full"]];
}
@catch (NSException * e)
{
    //Sorry...
}
```

Meanwhile, you need a class in your app that handles the StoreKit notifications. I mentioned that it's async; well, it still is. In my case, I used the AppDelegate for that:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <..., SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
```

And you designate the app delegate as one:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //...
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
}
```

And then you implement the transaction processing method:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)q updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)tr
{
    int i, n = [tr count];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        SKPaymentTransaction *t = [tr objectAtIndex:i];
        if(t.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased)
            [self ProcessPurchase: t.payment.productIdentifier];

        //Support for restored transactions
        if(t.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored)
            [self ProcessPurchase: t.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];

        //Failed/purchased/restored
        if(t.transactionState != SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing)
            [q finishTransaction:t];
}

-(void)ProcessPurchase:(NSString*)ProgID
{
    if([ProgID compare:@"com.mydomain.myproduct.full"] == 0)
    {
        //It's an upgrade! Change the settings, enable hidden content, and stuff...
    }
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: yes, thanks for your suggestion i am also thinking for the same, but i dont know how this works. cna you suggest me step by step. thanks lot

Comment: Thanks.. now i have response count 0 what can be the solution. i have created new app for in app purchase on itunes account but i m getting count 0 , can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate bundle id for your full version. as these are two different application.